All iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later
When i try to upload my ios archive to storeconnect, i am getting this error. I understand that my machine is old and i am able to use xcode 14.1 but not any further than that. Does this mean my machine is no use anymore?

Essentially, yes. You can look at using a cloud build service, such as Xcode cloud build, but you really need to be using Xcode 15 now

You don't need a brand new Mac, just a newer one. Your current computer must be like 10 years old

We need Xcode 15, as Apple announced:

App Store Connect upload requirement starts April 29
February 6, 2024
Apps uploaded to App Store Connect must be built with Xcode 15 for iOS
17, iPadOS 17, tvOS 17, or watchOS 10, starting April 29, 2024.

And newer macOS version, as written in Xcode 15 Release Notes:

Xcode 15 requires a Mac running macOS Ventura 13.5 or later.

That is why we need such Mac or newer.
